# VBA ADO connections without revealing password

Tags: sql-server, vba, azure-sql-database

I have a small SQL server DB on azure and I want to distribute among 10-20 users an Excel file with a VBA ADO connection to the SQL Server and pulls and update data from the Excel.

All the code is working perfect, my problem is security.

As you probably know, even if my excel VBA section is locked with password, this password is very easy to crack/hack.

I don’t care about the VBA code, I care about the SQL Server info especially the password.

I'm very new with SQL server and azure so I don’t know if I have tools to defend the SQL Server from access it if someone crack the Excel file and have all the "info connections".

I thought maybe there is a technique to connect the SQL Server with some kind of Token instead of the password in the ADO VBA?

Or if there is another solution I will be happy to know.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you need them to use a password, can you give them a role to log into, where the role will control what they see?

Comment: until now I didnt know that there is a "roles" options in the sql server, I need to learn about this topic to see if it can help me.

Comment: You can use a token to authenticate to Azure SQL Database https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-aad-authentication-configure#azure-ad-token